# How to access a property of an object from an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, properties, nsmutablearray, frame, sigabrt

In my program, I am trying to set the property 'frame' of an object stored in an NSMutableArray. When I try to set the frame of the object, my program receives the signal 'SIGABRT' with the message '__[NSCFNumber setFrame:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a8d960.' How do I fix this?

> for (int i = 0; i < [computerHand count]; i++) 
>     {
>
> > ```
> >    CardView* card = [computerHand objectAtIndex:i];
> >    card.frame = CGRectMake(10+70*i, 340, 60, 85);
> > ```
> >
> > }

declaration of computerHand:

> @property(retain) NSMutableArray* computerHand;

population of computerHand

```
-(void) addCardToHand:(NSMutableArray *)hand
{
    [hand addObject:[cards objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSLog(@"%@", [[cards objectAtIndex:0]class]);
    [cards removeObjectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Note- The NSLog prints '__NSCFNumber' to the console.

code for deck population

```
-(void) createDeck : (UIView *)view
{
    cards = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:52];
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= 13; j++)
        {
            CardView* card = [[CardView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(view.center.x - 60/2, view.center.y - 85/2, 60, 85) value:j];
            [cards addObject:card];
            [view addSubview:card];
        }
    }
    for(int i =0; i<= 52; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", [cards objectAtIndex:i]);
    }
}
```

Note: the NSLog command correctly prints a CardView object to the console, but then prints __NSCFNumber when trying to access it from a different scope.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are trying to set the frame property to NSNumber instance, Check your array for all the valid object that has, and bit more code will be easy to solve your issue.

Comment: @chiLLer, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: Show the code where you create the `computerHand` object; I bet it's being released too soon. It it's not that, can you show the code where you create the card and add it to the `computerHand`

Comment: The issue here is that the object at index `i` in the array `computerHand` is NOT a CardView object.  There is no compile-time checking for array accesses like this. The value in the array is an NSNumber, thus doesn't have a `frame` property. You should probably look at the code where you insert objects into the `computerHand` array (which you've not included here). I suspect you'll find that you're not actually putting objects of type `CardView` into the array. (Because an NSNumber is getting in there somehow.)

Comment: @ipmcc you are right, the objects in the array are of type NSNumber rather than CardView. I will have to track down where I made this mistake. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Dude as i mentioned early you've just shown us the issue raiser location, but it's necessary to know the cause for the issue (i meant the codes where you populating your array with objects) . . . I bet on it there must be some mistakes. One quick way to know , before inserting the object in to an array check for the types of class it is(`[object class]` where 'class' is a keyword and object is your variable). Let us know the result

Comment: @chiLLerthe population code is now listed above

Comment: Your `cards` is not the object you are expecting, it is NSNumber as I said earlier, make sure what object the cards hold, what you really store into your cards array(what ever but your code has only NSNumber).Can you show the code....

Comment: @chiLLer deck population code listed above

Comment: `for(int i =0; i<= 52; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", [cards objectAtIndex:i]);
    }` log all of your cards and check (where you getting issue).

Comment: Is your `cards` array a retain/strong property? Have you tried using `self.cards` instead? If you're not using `self` the array may be getting autoreleased.

Comment: @MishieMoo the cards array is a retain property, and i have tried to use self.cards. It still prints the same output to the console. The problem is when I try to access the card array from a scope other than the one it was created in, each object in it is an __NSFCNumber

Comment: And, just checking, but these methods are all in the same class correct?

Comment: @Fitzy had you tried to cast them while iterating;

Comment: Okay, I figured out what was wrong: I had declared a method that is supposed to swap two CardViews in the array, but instead of replacing it with a CardView, I was replacing it with an NSNumber. Thanks for all your help guys, it was just a silly mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you're not getting the correct object out of your array. If you break right after you get your `CardView` out of your array, and print the description in the console, it's a string and not actually a `CardView`. There are two things you need to do.

1. Make sure you only add CardViews to your array. Double check this.
2. In your for loop you can do this to make sure you are only setting frames on CardViews:

   ```
   if([card isMemberOfClass:[CardView class]]) {
        card.frame = CGRectMake(10+70*i, 340, 60, 85);
   }
   ```

You still want to make sure that you're actually only putting in CardViews though, but this is a way to debug.